# Swift - How can i change revise the frame of this table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHLka.png)

How can i resize this table view so that I can place 2 buttons in the top of the screen without overlapping with the table view? On my screen I only have the button. there is no table view container.

My code:

```
class FriendListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var friendArray: [Friends] = [];

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)


    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Friends", inManagedObjectContext:
    managedObjectContext)

    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    var friendObjs = [Friends]()

    do {
        friendObjs = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Friends]
    }
        catch {
            // show something
    }
    for friend in friendObjs {
        friendArray.append(friend)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return friendArray.count;
}

// assign the values in your array variable to a cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel!.text = friendArray[indexPath.row].firstName;
    return cell;
}

// Register when user taps a cell via alert message
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Selected Item", message: "clicked", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: your tableView property is an IBOutlet...do you have it set up in your storyboard?

Comment: @BJHStudios yes but the data is not being written in that tableview. instead it is being written on the base view container.

Comment: if it is connected to your storyboard for that view controller via IBOutlet, the best way to control the size of the table view is by adding layout constraints.  Have you worked with them?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a header view which contains your buttons. This would require setting the headerView property of the tableView or using tableView delegate methods.

Another option is to add a view and add it to the top of your frame. You would then need to adjust the frame of the table view upon initialize to add it below that custom view.

Something I noticed as well in order for your data to appear is to reload the table view after your fetch completes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried putting a tableview header, You can create a view and set the frames matching your need and add 2 buttons. set the tableview's tableviewviewheader property  with the view object you just created.

```
let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50))
```

Add your buttons as subview to headerView and then

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```